# Class organization in Java

Tags: java

I need to represent intervals of values for different data types in java. I worked out an abstract class `Interval` with the signatures of methods performing simple operations on intervals like sum, moltiplication... .

Every subclass of `Interval` must work on a different type of interval (basically ints and floats), but I don't know how to organize class fields (just lower and greatest bound) to have a good quality code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The other thing: if you already had some really working code of "some" quality, then you could take *that* code to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance isn't your core priority, you could consider using reference types instead of primitive types, like:

```
public class <T extends Number> Interval {
   public Interval(T lowerBound, T upperBound) { ...

   public boolean isIn(T value) { ...
```

to then use that like

```
 Interval<Integer> intInterval = new Interval<>(10, 100);
 Interval<Double> doubleInterval = new Interval<>(42.42, 199.99);
```

In other words: you can often rely on (un)boxing by the compiler to turn primitive values into the corresponding reference type.

The downside: doing "maths" on Double, Integer, ... objects is more expensive than using their primitive counterparts.

That is about what can be said **without** you providing any code for us to look into.

Comment: I just needed tips to build a good project. Thanks for your helpful answer.

Comment: Then use generics if your methods work the generic way. e.g. the end of a list of strings is the same implementation as it is with a list of integers. but the sum of integers will not match the implementation of the sum of strings (whatever that is).

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is an educational question.
I would also use generics (type parameters) but I am not sure it is already part of the required functionality.

So it not just put the function signatures into the interface (your abstract class) and put the different implementation and also the different collections into the inherited children.

EDIT: typing